# How to put custom data into a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

Ok everybody, so i have a question.

I am making a game where I want to store the state of the game in a JSON file. However, there are some custom classes that I want to store inside the JSON file. Does anyone know how you would do this?

I'm writing in Python using the `json` library.

Further examples for clarification:

main.py:
`class Rectangle(): #code and stuff`

save.json:
`{"favorite_shape": #class defined in main.py}`

Please comment if you need anything else.

Comment: I think this has some misconceptions.. if you want to save and rebuild objects, you can save all the properties which one might want to adjust. For example that the shape is a rectangle and its width and length.

Comment: so your saying to make a list that contains all the favorite shapes, and then describe all the properties of the object? @ti7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would achieve this is to implement `__repr__()`

```
class Something_To_Save:
    self.a = 5
    self.b = "stuff"

    def __repr__(self):                      # for representing as a string
        return self.a + ";" + self.b

    def load_from_str(self, representation): # for loading from a string rep.
        split = representation.split(";")
        self.a, self.b = split[0], split[1]
```

and then you can just convert those objects to representing strings, like

```
foo = Something_To_Save()
representation = repr(foo)   # "5;stuff"
```

and store that `representation` in a json file.

If you wanted to load those object from a json file, you can add another method:

```
def load_from_str(self, representation):
    split = representation.split(";")
    self.a, self.b = split[0], split[1]
```

Feel free to adjust these as required, however, this is the general idea for me.

Comment: Great! If that helped, feel free to accept and upvote :D Good luck with your project